# how to get sum of column value with inner join in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join

i have one table name as a_ad_display in that i have following table

```
advId | Displaytime
```

I have One a_advertise table with following collumn

```
advertiseId| advertisename| mediaTypeId
```

I have one a_mediatype table with following collumn

```
mediaTypeId | medianame

1 | Image
2 | Animation
3 | video
```

there is multiple entry of advId in the a_display table

i want to fetch the sum of adv display with their mediaType like how much video ,image and animation type of advertise in a_display table

i have done this way

```
SELECT 
  mdtype.medianame AS _type,
  SUM(mdtype.medianame = 'Image') AS _display 
FROM
  a_ad_display a 
  INNER JOIN a_advertise adv 
    ON adv.advertiseId = a.advId 
  INNER JOIN a_mediatype mdtype 
    ON mdtype.mediaId = adv.mediaTypeId 
GROUP BY medianame ;
```

but i got following results

[image]

but if write just sum(distinct mdtype.medianame) then its givng me error...so how can i get all the values of image video and animation in just one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    m.medianame,
    COUNT(as.advId) as Total
FROM    a_mediatype as m
INNER JOIN a_advertise as a ON a.mediaTypeId = m.mediaTypeId
INNER JOIN  a_ad_display as ad ON ad.advId = a.advertiseId
GROUP BY m.mediaTypeId
```

Comment: perfect...as what i want...thanx

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
SELECT mdtype.medianame as _type, SUM(mdtype.medianame) as _display
FROM a_ad_display a
INNER JOIN a_advertise adv ON ad.advertiseID=a.advId
INNER JOIN a_mediatype mdtype ON mdtype.mediaID=adv.mediaTypeId
GROUP BY _type
HAVING DISTINCT(_type)
```

Comment: sorry...your query have error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT(_type)
GROUP BY _type' at line 5"

Comment: I thought you were asking for the sum. haha! Sorry :)
I've changed the sequence of what I've commented.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT m.mediaTypeId, 
       MIN(m.medianame) AS `type`, 
       COUNT(m.mediaTypeId) AS `count`
  FROM a_ad_display a LEFT JOIN 
       a_advertise d on d.advertiseId=a.advId LEFT JOIN 
       a_mediatype m on m.mediaId=d.mediaTypeId 
GROUP BY m.mediaTypeId
```

Comment: thanx for answer...just one thing in yr answer is need to change as GroupBy Only m.mediaTypeId....otherwise both of u were right u and   @raheel shan..thanx

Comment: Sorry, misread. I thought you need it on per ad basis. Changed the answer. And you're certainly welcome. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT
    m.medianame,
    COUNT(as.advId) as Total
FROM a_mediatype as m
INNER JOIN a_advertise as a 
ON a.mediaTypeId = m.mediaTypeId
INNER JOIN  a_ad_display as ad 
ON ad.advId = a.advertiseId
GROUP BY m.mediaTypeId
```